# How to allow non staff upload pictures with Django-TinyMCE and FileBrowser?

Tags: django, tinymce

I'm using 
  * Django 1.3
  * Django-TinyMCE 1.5 trunk
  * Filebrowser 3.4

Now if I login with an account which is_staff, I could upload pictures via TinyMCE's insert image button. While if it is not a staff, the pop up window will redirect to django admin login page and if I login with is_staff account, the pictures will be listed.

How could I allow non staff to upload picture?

Answer (score 0):

1. Override the clean method in the AdminAuthenticationForm class
2. Create a view outside the admin where a user can upload
3. Make the user staff

You do realize that if you do point 1 or 3 the user will have access to the whole admin section? That is probably not what you want so you should go with point 2.

Comment: Is there a sample about option 2?